# Recycler view not update itself

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview

I have a problem with recycler view. In my previous app, when i get the list for recycler view adapter from database and observe it in my fragment, i used the notifyDataSetChanged() and when i tried to delete a item , view updated successfully. But in this app this does not work and i don't understand why. When i click the delete button the item deleted in database successfully but i can't see it immediatly. When i go to any other fragment and back to this Favourites fragment i see the items deleted.
I tried all the options in stackoverflow but still i can't fix it.
My Adapter:

```
class FavouritesAdapter(owner: ViewModelStoreOwner, val favouritesList : ArrayList<Vocabulary>) : RecyclerView.Adapter<FavouritesAdapter.FavouritesViewHolder>() {
    val viewModel = ViewModelProvider(owner).get(FavouritesViewModel::class.java)

    class FavouritesViewHolder(val binding: FavouritesItemRowBinding) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(binding.root)


    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): FavouritesViewHolder {
        return FavouritesViewHolder(FavouritesItemRowBinding.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(parent.context), parent, false))

    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: FavouritesViewHolder, position: Int) {
        holder.binding.englishWordTV.text = favouritesList[position].word
        holder.binding.turkishWordTV.text = favouritesList[position].translation

        holder.binding.deleteButtonRV.setOnClickListener {
            viewModel.deleteVocabulary(favouritesList[position])
            notifyDataSetChanged()
        }

    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return favouritesList.size
    }
    fun updateList(myList : List<Vocabulary>) {
        favouritesList.clear()
        favouritesList.addAll(myList)
        notifyDataSetChanged()

    }


}
```

My problem is in delete button in my recycler row;

```
holder.binding.deleteButtonRV.setOnClickListener {
            viewModel.deleteVocabulary(favouritesList[position])
            notifyDataSetChanged()
        }
```

And here is my fragment ;

```
class FavouritesFragment : Fragment() {
    private var _binding: FragmentFavouritesBinding? = null
    private val binding get() = _binding!!
    private lateinit var favouritesAdapter : FavouritesAdapter
    private lateinit var viewModel : FavouritesViewModel


    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View {
        _binding = FragmentFavouritesBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)
        return binding.root


    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        viewModel = ViewModelProvider(this).get(FavouritesViewModel::class.java)
        favouritesAdapter = FavouritesAdapter(this, arrayListOf())
        viewModel.getAllVocabulariesFromDB()

        prepareRecyclerView()
        observeFavouritesLiveData()
    }


    fun prepareRecyclerView(){
        binding.favouritesRecyclerView.apply {
            layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(context)
            adapter = favouritesAdapter
        }
    }

    fun observeFavouritesLiveData(){
        viewModel.favouritesListLiveData.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer {

            it?.let {
                favouritesAdapter.updateList(it)
            }
        })
    }

    override fun onDestroyView() {
        super.onDestroyView()
        _binding = null


    }
    
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i tried to use the path "button click -> UI sends delete event to VM -> VM updates data -> observer sees new data -> observer calls update with new data" as @cactuctictacs mentioned. I added this lines to my adapter,

```
lateinit var onDeleteItemClick : ((Vocabulary) -> Unit)
```

```
holder.binding.deleteButtonRV.setOnClickListener {
        onDeleteItemClick.invoke(favouritesList[position])
        notifyItemRemoved(position)
  }
```

and added to my fragment,

```
fun deleteButtonClicked(){
        favouritesAdapter.onDeleteItemClick = {
            viewModel.deleteVocabulary(it)
            viewModel.getAllVocabulariesFromDB()

            observeFavouritesLiveData()
            favouritesAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
        }
    }
```

I hope this is the proper way to do this.

Comment: You should already be observing ``favouritesListLiveData`` - the observer you wrote calls `favouritesAdapter.updateList(it)` which is correct - when you get new data for your *favourites list*, you want to push that to your adapter so it can display it. All your button needs to do is call `deleteVocabulary(it)` on your VM - that's it, inform it of that event. The VM should work out *what to do with that information*, including saving data, and updating its `LiveData`s including your favs list one. When that updates, the observer automatically displays it. You don't need to do anything manually

Comment: Have a look around this section for some general ideas (I'm not talking about the *UI state* idea here, more the way that events are handled by informing the VM, and just responding to the resulting observer updates as usual): https://developer.android.com/topic/architecture/ui-layer/events

Answer (score 1):

Try with `notifyItemRemoved(position)` instead of `notifyDataSetChanged()`.

Answer (score 1):

It all looks fine to me - you observe the *favourites* `LiveData`, that passes the new data to an update function in your `Adapter`, and that modifies the internal data set and calls `notifyDataSetChanged()` (which works for any kind of update).

So, are you sure your `ViewModel` is updating `favouritesListLiveData` properly when you call `deleteVocabulary`? Check if your observer is actually firing with a new value when you hit delete, and check if its contents are what you expect (the previous list minus the thing you want removed)

You could check it with some logging, but setting some breakpoints and debugging the app might be more helpful if you're not sure where it's going wrong

(also your button doesn't need to call `notifyDataSetChanged()` - that only needs to happen when the data is updated, which happens through the `update` function, in there is the right place for it!)

Comment: Thank you so much for your answers, i realized that it is not enough to remove the instance from database i also added this lines on delete button onClickListener,             favouritesList.remove(favouritesList[position]) and i fixed the problem.

Comment: @Ugur that's not the way it should work - your `update` function makes the adapter show *the current state of the list*, and you get the current state by *observing* that `LiveData` in the ViewModel. It should go like this: *button click -> UI sends delete event to VM -> VM updates data -> observer sees new data -> observer calls `update` with new data*. Your button shouldn't be skipping that and interfering with the adapter directly! In that case you're not really using the VM at all - and if it works, it implies your VM isn't actually removing the item you want to remove

Comment: First of all, thank you for your answer. i am a newbie in kotlin and every suggestion is really precious for me. i changed my code and it works fine now, i tried to use the path "button click -> UI sends delete event to VM -> VM updates data -> observer sees new data -> observer calls update with new data" as you mentioned. I am adding the changes below as an answer.